# OBIEE prompts for separate reports interlinked

Tags: prompt, obiee

I have two separate reports on a page in OBIEE, each having its own prompt. Both the prompts are on the same column in a subject area. The problem is that when I change the value in one of these prompts, the other one also automatically changes. I do not want this to happen i.e I want them to remain independent of each other. I have changed the scope of both prompts to 'dashboard', but the problem still exists.

How can this be done? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you may want to try changing the scope of the prompt to 'Page' and changing the break on the column containing the second prompt & Answer to 'Page Break with Column Break' first. I believe when I've tried it before though, that didn't work.

Otherwise, you can make a subtle edit to the column formula in one of the prompts and corresponding Answers. Essentially what you need to do is make OBI think the column is different in each prompt. Obviously you don't actually want to change the column result, so a neat way to do it is if it's a string append an empty string to the end, if it's a number then add 0 to it.

- CONCAT("My Dimension"."My String Column", '')
- "My Dimension"."My Number Column" + 0

Make sure to do that in one of the prompts and the Answers you want that prompt to affect.